# Unable to run in iOS simulator after upgrading Xcode 14.3 react native

Tags: react-native, xcode14.3

Building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/ios/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks/GooglePlaces.framework/GooglePlaces' for architecture arm64

I am able to make build (archive) but unable to run in simulator in xcode 14.3 in react native

I tried to run in simulator